# RSS feed found on page is considered invalid, but displays in embedded segment

Tags: xml, rss

I wanted to grab the RSS feed [of a website with an embedded segment](http://www.idug-db2.com/) but could not. After using temper data I found out the XML led to a feed but one that does not validate. I tested the [validity of the feed](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-validator/) which returned the following:

> It looks like this is a web page, not a feed. I looked for a feed associated with this page, but couldn't find one. Please enter the address of your feed to validate.

Looking [at the source code of this XML](http://www.brighttalk.com//service/channel/xml/feed/7637) (munged, truncated as below), it does not seems to be an HTML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:bt="http://example.com/2009/atom_extensions">
  <title>IDUG DB2 Tech Channel</title>
  <id>tag:example.com,2012:channel:7637</id>
  <bt:description>Desciption</bt:description>
  <subtitle>Joint DB2 Tech Talk series sponsored by IDUG with IBM</subtitle>
  <updated>2012-04-18T16:53:39Z</updated>
  <link href="http://www.example.org" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
  <link href="http://www.example.com/channel/7637/feed" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  <entry>
    <id>tag:example.com,2012:communication:47115</id>
    <title>DB2 Tech Talk: Oracle Database and PL/SQL Compatibility Features of DB2 10</title>
    <updated>2012-05-31T16:30:00Z</updated>
    <summary>blah blah</summary>
    <author>
      <name>Serge Rielau</name>
    </author>
    <bt:communication id="47115"/>
    <bt:channel id="7637"/>
    <bt:status>upcoming</bt:status>
    <bt:format>audio</bt:format>
    <bt:duration>5400</bt:duration>
    <bt:start>1338481800</bt:start>
    <bt:entryTime>1338481500</bt:entryTime>
    <bt:closeTime>1338487500</bt:closeTime>
    <bt:rating>0</bt:rating>
    <link href="http://www.example.org?commid=47115" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
    <link href="http://www.example.com/communication/47115/tn1_1.png" rel="enclosure" type="image/png" title="thumbnail"/>
    <link href="http://www.example.com/communication/47115/slide1_001.png" rel="related" type="image/png" title="preview"/>
    <link href="http://www.example.com/communication/47115/calendar/ics" rel="related" type="text/calendar" title="calendar"/>
    <category scheme="keyword" term="DB2"/>
    <category scheme="keyword" term="Oracle"/>
    <category scheme="keyword" term="Database"/>
    <category scheme="keyword" term="PL/SQL"/>
    <category scheme="keyword" term="compatibility"/>
    <category scheme="keyword" term="SQL"/>
  </entry>
  ...
</feed>
```

Why is this not a valid RSS feed? Does the page at http://www.idug-db2.com/ have an RSS feed that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

RSS is a type of XML which has its own defined set of elements that must appear in order for it to be valid.

> [RSS is a dialect of XML](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html). All RSS files must conform to the XML 1.0 specification, as published on the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) website.

It's like how winged elves and miner dwarves are humanoids, but they're not built the same. Same thing you have here. It's a valid XML feed which the site is capable of eating and digesting as it needs to in the embedded portion.

But it's not a valid RSS feed as it doesn't have the required elements as well as adding in others that do not fall in the RSS specifications.

If you have a parser that can interpret the XML feed source as needed, or you can write your own class/method, then the one you're looking at will do. As the example site has done.

Just not for those readers or parsers that expect RSS in a format as defined by the specs.